# Stainless Steel Rat warp drive?

Tags: space, science

In The Stainless Steel Rat universe, space ships would often travel quickly across the galaxy. There was one case when DiGriz traveled a long distance to meet an alien race. I can't remember if the ships had warp dive/warp jump/hyper jump/hyper speed abilities. Did they?

Comment: About time we had some Stainless Steel Rat questions :)

Comment: I want to learn Harrison's writing style, so I'm writing a short story like his original Stainless Steel Rat. Warp drive may affect the plot :P

Comment: @XosMel - You actually have two choices; point-and-shoot Warp drive (like Star Trek) or Babylon-5 style hyperspace with beacons.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the world of Stainless Steel Rat they have both FTL communication (in the form of FTL transmitters) and FTL travel (in the form of warp drives):

> "**So they are already in warpdrive and cannot be contacted until they
>   emerge."** I considered the possibilities. "You will of course be in
>   touch with the authorities at their scheduled destination. <sub>[The Stainless Steel Rat goes to Hell](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/286219.The_Stainless_Steel_Rat_Goes_to_Hell)</sub>

and

> “Bang on.” I had forgotten that he was an engineer. “An FTL
>   transmission, faster than light, is almost instantaneous, even at
>   stellar distances. But radio waves move at the speed of light—and how
>   far is the nearest star from here?” ‘Three point two light-years.”
>   <sub>[The Stainless Steel Rat gets Drafted](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/710706.The_Stainless_Steel_Rat_Gets_Drafted)</sub>

There are a few rules that seem to be fairly common across the various novels;

- Warp drives are powered by "generators" (this is a key point of the second novel)
- Warp drives allow you to access "warp space".
- Newer drives are somehow *better* (there's no explanation why this is the case)
- When traveling in warp space, you cannot receive conventional or FTL communications.
- When traveling in warp space, you cannot interact with normal matter and are therefore largely immune from attack.

---

Interestingly, in the "[Stainless Steel Visions](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/710841.Stainless_Steel_Visions)" collection of short stories (published in 1994 but written substantially earlier) the rules are **substantially different**. No mention of warp drives, now it's all about hyperspace transit using beacons.

> To understand the importance of the beacons, you have to understand
>   hyperspace. Not that many people do, but it is easy enough to
>   understand that in this nonspace the regular rules don't apply. Speed
>   and measurements are a matter of relationship, not constant facts like
>   the fixed universe.
>
> The first ships to enter hyperspace had no place to go—and no way to
>   even tell if they had moved. The beacons solved that problem and
>   opened the entire universe. They're built on planets and generate
>   tremendous amounts of power. This power is turned into radiation that
>   is punched through into hyperspace. Every beacon has a code signal
>   that is part of its radiation and represents a measurable point in
>   hyperspace. Triangulation and quadrature of the beacons works for
>   navigation—only it follows its own rules. The rules are complex and
>   variable, but they are still rules that a navigator can follow.
>
> For a hyperspace jump, you need at least four beacons for an accurate
>   fix. For long jumps, navigators use as many as seven or eight. So
>   every beacon is important and every one has to keep operating. That is
>   where I and the other troubleshooters come in.